# overflow:hidden not working when using tables

Tags: html, css

I’m having issues with long strings of text stretching out my tables and `overflow:hidden` does not seem to be doing what I exect. Here’s the sample code I am using to test this effect:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            td.scroll
            {
                background-color:#00FFFF;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                overflow:scroll;
            }
            td.hidden 
            {
                background-color:#00FF00;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="scroll">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td class="scroll">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td class="scroll">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hidden">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td class="hidden">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td class="hidden">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When loaded, the text will, regardless of the table width, stretch out to display all of the string. What I’m after is to have any part of the string that would go past the cell measurement not be display. Is this even possible with tables, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Overflow only works on block level elements. Table elements aren't block elements. If you want to get those effects put a `<div>` inside the table cell and apply the effects to the `<div>`.

```
td.scroll div {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

td.hidden div {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

with:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
  <td><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
  <td><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
  <td><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="scroll"><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
  <td class="scroll"><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
  <td class="scroll"><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="hidden"><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
  <td class="hidden"><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
  <td class="hidden"><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot for this and saving what's left of my hair! Guess I need to read up on my css some more.

Comment: It's a fairly arcane aspect to CSS. The only time anyone finds it out is when they have this exact problem. Believe me, been there done that.

Comment: CSS 2.1 says that `overflow` does work on table cells. However in reality only WebKit supports scrolling on cells. `hidden` works OK though.

Comment: Please don't put block-level elements inside inline-level elements. You can simply just set the `<td>` to `display: inline-block' to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 23):

By default the auto-table-layout mechanism expands the table width to fit the minimum cell content width. Tell it not to do that with the [table-layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-table-layout) property:

```
<table width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed">
```

and your example works as expected. You should probably also remove the `width: 100px` from the table cells, since that makes no sense in combination with a 100%-width table. (Although with fixed table layout it doesn't matter, as only the first row of cells or `<col>`s has any bearing on the column widths.)

Note `overflow: scroll` or `auto` doesn't work for table cells in most browsers. (It does in WebKit.)

Comment: "Table-layout: fixed" doesn't change a thing. The height still expands. Tested on chrome which is webkit

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td { width: 33%; height: 2em; }
td div { width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<table border="1" style="width:300px;">
<tr><td>x</td><td><div>y</div></td><td>z</td></tr>
<tr><td>x</td><td><div>this is going to be hidden because it is too long</div></td><td>z</td></tr>
<tr><td>x</td><td><div>y</div></td><td>z</td></tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it isn't supposed to be working for table cells, but ideally you don't really want to hide them anyway. I suggest you hyphenate long words, which you can do easily with the following lib (only take few lines of js to implement):

http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/

Example:

http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%202.2.0/WorkingExample.html

Comment: Was thinking of something something similar, but unfortunately that design decision is not up to me.